# Asynchronous data load by parallel sessions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Looking for help with a data load function designed to support asynchronous execution by parallel sessions.
Process_Log table contains the list of data load functions, with current status and a list of upstream dependencies.
Each session first looks for a function that is ready for execution, calls it, and updates status.
For further details please see comments in the code.

In Oracle PL/SQL I would design it as a nested block within the loop, and autonomous transaction for status updates.
Not sure how to achieve that in Postgres. Running 9.2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dm_operations.dm_load()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

declare
    _run_cnt integer;
    _ready_cnt integer;
    _process_id dm_operations.process_log.process_id%type;
    _exec_name dm_operations.process_log.exec_name%type;
    _rowcnt dm_operations.process_log.rows_affected%type;
    _error text;
    _error_text text;
    _error_detail text;
    _error_hint text;
    _error_context text;

begin

  loop

--(1) Find one function ready to run

    select sum(case when process_status = 'RUNNING' then 1 else 0 end) run_cnt,
           sum(case when process_status = 'READY'  then 1 else 0 end) ready_cnt,
           min(case when  process_status = 'READY' then process_id end) process_id
    into _run_cnt, _ready_cnt, _process_id
    from dm_operations.process_log; --One row per each executable data load function

--(2) Exit loop if nothing is ready

    if _ready_cnt = 0 then exit;
    else

--(3) Lock the row until the status is updated

    select exec_name
    into _exec_name
    from dm_operations.process_log
    where process_id = _process_id
    for update;

--(4) Set status of the function to 'RUNNING'
--New status must be visible to other sessions

    update dm_operations.process_log
    set process_status = 'RUNNING',
        start_ts = now()
    where process_id = _process_id;

--(5) Release lock. (How?)

--(6) Execute data load function. See example below.
-- Is this correct syntax for dynamic call to a function that returns void?

    execute 'perform dm_operations.'||_exec_name;

--(7) Get number of rows processed by the data load function

    GET DIAGNOSTICS _rowcnt := ROW_COUNT;

--(8) Upon successful function execution set status to 'SUCCESS'

    update dm_operations.process_log
    set process_status = 'SUCCESS',
        end_ts = now(),
        rows_affected = _rowcnt
    where process_id = _process_id;

--(9) Check dependencies and update status
--These changes must be visible to the next loop iteration, and to other sessions

    update dm_operations.process_log pl1 
    set process_status = 'READY'
    where process_status is null
    and not exists (select null from dm_operations.process_log pl2
    where pl2.process_id in (select unnest(pl1.depends_on))
    and (coalesce(pl2.process_status,'NULL') <> 'SUCCESS'));


    end if;

--(10) Log error and allow the loop to continue

    EXCEPTION
    when others then
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS _error_text = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                              _error_detail = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                              _error_hint = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
                              _error_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
      _error := _error_text||
                _error_detail||
                _error_hint||
                _error_context;

    update dm_operations.process_log
    set process_status = 'ERROR',
        start_ts = now(),
        rows_affected = _rowcnt,
        error_text = _error
    where process_id = _process_id;

    end;

  end loop;

end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Data load function example (6):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_target()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

begin

execute 'truncate table target_table';

insert into target_table 
select ...
from source_table;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start asynchronous operations in PL/pgSQL.

There are two options I can think of:

1. The hard way: Upgrade to a more recent PostgreSQL version and write a [background worker](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bgworker.html) in C that executes `load_target`. You'd have to use
2. Don't write your function in the database, but on the client side. Then you can simply open several database sessions and run functions in parallel that way.

Comment: Launching multiple sessions is not a problem. It is done by external process, all sessions executing the same dm_load() function above. What I need to figure out is how to implement updates to the control table (process_log) in a way that avoids two sessions executing the same data load function (identified by exec_name) at the same time.